# Array in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have the following piece of code, to get data from IMDB :

```
for(var i in titles)
{
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=" + titles[i],
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {

        $('body').append('"'+titles[i]+'",');
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $('body').append('"'+val+'",');
        });
        $('body').append('<br>');
        window.setTimeout(null, 1000);
      }
    });
}
```

The code works ok, except for `$('body').append('"'+titles[i]+'",');` which alway returns the same title.

Comment: titles[i] always returns the same title

Comment: Repeating yourself is clearly not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop executes completely before any of the success handlers are called, so when you get into a success handler "i" will be the last title.

You need something like

```
function makeSuccessHandler(titles, i) {
    return function (data) {
        $('body').append('"'+titles[i]+'",');
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $('body').append('"'+val+'",');
        });
        $('body').append('<br>');
        window.setTimeout(null, 1000);
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++)
{
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=" + titles[i],
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: makeSuccessHandler(titles, i)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `success` function is asynchronous (it needs to wait for imdb to respond), so it will always run **after** the entire loop has finished - so `i`, within that function, will always be the last `i`.

Easiest way to work around this is to utilise jQuery's `each` function:

```
$.each(titles, function (i, value) {
    $.ajax({
        success: function (data) {
            // as usual...
        }
    });
});
```

This works because a function preserves its own scope (and hence its own copy of `i`).

Comment: +1 - I think this is more elegant than having a handler function outside of the block.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it like that, the ajax call will execute asynchronous.
When your success method is executed the value of your index variable will not be correct.
You can fix it if you increment i from your sucess method, and ofcoruse not do a for loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you call an asynchronous function in a loop, it will use the last assigned value of enclosing variables.

This can be solved using [currying](http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-curry/)

```
function appendTitle(var title)
{
    return function(var data) {
        $('body').append('"'+title+'",');
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $('body').append('"'+val+'",');
        });
        $('body').append('<br>');
        window.setTimeout(null, 1000);
    }
}


for(var i in titles)
{
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=" + titles[i],
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: appendTitle(titles[i])
    });
}
```